# Examples of continuous/discontinuous functions where one's intuition fails

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions, continuity

If I understand correctly, the formal definition of a continuous function $f:X \to Y$ is when

$$
\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=f(c)
$$

Where $c$ is a constant, and $\{x,c\} \in X$. The layman explanation I was given by my schoolteacher was that a function is continuous if you can draw the graph without your pen going off the page. I only know of one exception to this intuition:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ has a point of discontinuity at $x=0$, but is still a *continuous* function because it has no discontinuities in its range:

$X=\mathbb R-\{0\}$

(Side question: am I misusing the equals sign in the above expression?)

Are there other examples of a:

1. Continuous function where you must take your pen off the page?
2. Discontinuous function where you don't have to take your pen off the page?

(Please note that for question $1$, I'd be more interested in examples that aren't similar to the one I have already given.)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The pen analogy does not work when $X$ is disconnected.  In your numbered questions, you might change the verbs to 1. Continuous function where you *must* take your pen off the page? 2. Discontinuous function where you *don't have to* take your pen off the page?

Comment: Since $\frac1x$ is undefined at $0$, it is neither continuous nor discontinuous there.

Comment: Suppose you had $f:[-1,1] \to [-1,1]$ where $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ when $x$ is irrational, and you draw a circle radius $1$ centred at $0,0$.  This circle covers the whole function, and assuming the thickness of the pen is an arbitrarily small positive number then every position of the pen covers an infinite number of cases of the function